# No entra en la exception del try cacht el error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Tengo un codigo ejecutandose en segundo plano en una api.

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private int horas = 0;
    private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
    private Timer _timer;
    
    public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");            
            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {

        TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(21, 0, 0); //12 am
        TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 0); //4 am
        TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        if ((now > start) && (now < end))//valida dentro del rango de horas
        {
          EnviarCorreo();
        }
     }

  public string procesa_boletas()
    {
       

        try
        {
         //codigo para obtener parametros y enviar al metodo siguiente
          obtiene_token(....,,,....);
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            enviaCorreoError();

            ///CrearArchivoTxt(cont_bd + "nombreempresa: " + nombreempresa + ex.Message);

        }
        finally
        {

        }
        return "";

    }

    public Tuple<int, string> obtiene_token(string nombreempresa, string paramsX509Certificate2server, string rutempresa, string pclavecertificado)
    {
        int retorno = 1;

        var linea = "";
        // Obtener Semilla - EO
        try
        {

            // codigo anterior no relevante
            XmlNode seedNodeToken = xmlToken.SelectSingleNode("//SII:RESP_BODY/TOKEN", namespaceManagerToken);  // se cae en esta linea, y no pasa al catch
            return Tuple.Create(retorno, token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CrearArchivoTxt("nombreempresa: " + nombreempresa + ex.Message);
            return Tuple.Create(-1, "-1");
        }
    }
}
```

El asunto está en que se cae en una linea del codigo XmlNode seedNodeToken, pero no pasa al catch, sino que se queda pegado en esa linea, quisiera saber porque, y como solucionarlo para que pase por el error. Saludos.

Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: SE queda pegado? en una linea que no pusiste en el codigo... y que no dice que hace ni nada.. como podemos saber que pasa?

Comment: @gbianchi, se queda pegado donde está declarado  XmlNode seedNodeToken. De referencia nula, pero quiero que salte al catch

Comment: @gbianchi, adjunte foto del error, si te das cuenta, se queda pegado ahí y no avanza al catch